# How to copy a range of cells while referencing last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy a selected range while using last row reference. I need the range to be (2,10) or C:M. The closest I have gotten is using the entire row reference, but that data isn't compatible with my destination.

This is what I have came up with:

```
lcopylastrow = _
        wscopy.Cells(wscopy.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Resize(2).EntireRow.Copy
```

Any help would be appreciated and let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Comment: I understand how to find the last row. I am trying to copy a fixed set of cells each time the macro is initiated.

Comment: `Copy` is a method of the `Range` object so it makes no sense to append it to the end of a line defining a row variable (presumably). I don't really understand your problem.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to copy columns C:M in the last row. I have only found a way to copy the entire row, but I dont need all the contents copied just a certain range. Sorry if I am not portraying the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be on one line?  Define the last row, then copy

```
lastrow = wscopy.Cells(wscopy.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
wscopy.Range(wscopy.Cells(lastrow, 3), wscopy.Cells(lastrow, 10)).Copy
```

Comment: The reason I resized it is because I’m copying two rows with those values. That showed an error when trying that code, but I appreciate a different tool to try with.

Comment: Just change the second one to `(lastrow + 1, 10)` and you will copy two rows

Comment: That definitely is the direction I need to go, but I am having issues getting the code to run.

Comment: You may have other issues that need to be asked as separate questions.  Knowing what `wscopy` is and how that range is set may be helpful.